# Move multiple unrelated uncommitted changes into several branches

Tags: git

Some files have been changed and some added, and nothing committed to master. I would like to checkout a new branch "login_fix" and commit the changes to two files to that branch (and probably merge it back into master immediately if the fix works). The rest of the files, some new and some modified, I would either commit to a different new branch, "big_mess," or I guess leave as uncommitted files if that is even possible.

Can I do that with git commands?

My other option is to `tar` all these files, `git reset --hard HEAD`, and then untar the files somewhere else and copy in the new files for each branch I want to create out of them.

`git status` shows:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

And it shows about 10 modified files and 6 added files, 2 of which appear to be renamed backup copies of files that were modified.

Comment: "big mess" sounds appropriate here.  How did you end up in a situation where you need to commit only 2 files?  That I am having a hard time constructing an exact answer to your question is indication that Git is not a file-based VCS, but is rather repository-based.  Your unit of work should be a commit of multiple files, not a single file.

Comment: Well the immediately pressing change is a quick fix to just two files. But the developer didn't bother reading instructions on how to use Git and has not created any separate branches for various changes. I'll have to fix the mess somehow.

Comment: Obviously I'm not a Git genius either. But I would have made a branch for the login fix, tested it, and then merged it into master.

Comment: What does `git status` show you?  Do you have a collection of modified files, with some belonging in one branch and some in the other?

Comment: It's all on a testing server with nothing pushed to GitHub ( I didn't give him write permission in case of this kind of issue), by the way.

Comment: `git status` says it's up to date with origin/master. But it's actually about 5 commits behind Github's version, since no one has `pull`ed here lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Do the following

On the "login_fix" branch do

```
git commit <file_1> <file_2>
```

Get the commit id(SHA value) of above commit using

```
git log
```

Now go to your master and do following. The "SHA_value" is the commit id you got from above "git log" command.

```
git cherry-pick <SHA_value>
```

If you want to leave the remaining files as uncommitted then you do not need to do anything. If you want to commit them to the branch "big_mess", then go to that branch and do

```
git commit <list_of_remaining_files>
```

Comment: It turns out there is also one commit on the server that conflicts with github. Is it possible to `git stash` and then `git reset --hard head` and then unstash and perform your already-suggested procedures?

Comment: You mean there is a commit on github server which conflicts with your changes? If you have a change made which is uncommitted and conflicts with github, then first you may want to stash your changes using "git stash". Then do a pull from github. Then you unstash, now your unstash will give you conflicts, which you need to resolve.

Comment: There is a local commit which looks like garbage. It has a similar commit message to one on Github but a different hash. I think the one on Github includes a change to .gitignore whereas this one doesn't.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the local commit, then first stash your changes then you need to do "git reset --hard HEAD~1" (this is assuming the local commit is the top most commit on your branch). Then do a pull from github to get the latest content and then unstash.

Comment: This seems to all be working perfectly. The `cherry-pick` apparently merges that commit into master? So now it seems like I can push the master branch and then Github will also have the "login_fix" merge at HEAD. Right now 2nd to last commit hash matches last on Github, so it's looking right to me.

Comment: I don't know if this question/answer will be useful for anyone else, but I'm glad I asked. My understanding of Git advanced a lot more from this one quirky exercise than I expected.